# How to order wise click elements in selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, web-scraping

This is a very odd question.
So, i want to scrape a website which has 15 elements at a time on the viewport, and it changes its 15 elements, and add new elements to the previous 15 elements when i scroll a down all the 15 elements.
The website has the elements not in order, i mean, that if such as you have 4 contacts in that website, the order shown in the website to normal user is this:

1. Mom
2. Dad
3. Son
4. Daughter
5. Sister
6. Maid

But, in the inspect element of these 6 elements, the order is like for mom the element is below Son elements, and Daughter is above Dad element.The sister and maid is not in the view port, nor in the source code, to get them in source code i have to scroll down to Sister.
Like the website is intentionally confusing us

**What i want is how can i click Mom,Dad,Son,Daughter,then like a normal user click Sister and then maid.So basically, i could defeat the website intentional confusion code**

The code i am using:

```
    while True:
        time.sleep(4)
        self.conversations = self.driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='_2wP_Y']")      # Get 15 elements
        for conversation in self.conversations:
            try:
                conversation.click()
            except Exception:
                pass
            time.sleep(7.5)
        time.sleep(3.5)
        print("Scrolling Down")
        self.driver.execute_script("var bar = document.getElementById('pane-side'); bar.scrollBy(0,2376)")
```

Thanks, Iam new in this, and i will later change the while condition

Comment: the logic would be much the same as for a human user, although you'll usually have IDs to go by which are more specific.   Post the site's HTML so someone can suggest proper locators.

Comment: What website are you trying to crawl?

Comment: @pcalkins i cant post the html here, its very long

Comment: @JQadrad iam trying to crawl  my whatsapp web conversations

Comment: So you are using some WhatsApp API? Not sure why it would intentionally create confusion? Is it illegal to scrape the data?

Comment: No, whatsapp doesnot has api to scrape non business whatsapp account, its not illegal because iam its my own chats

Comment: Iam not using any api

Comment: If the usernames are visible you can build a selector around that.

Comment: Selector means?And usernames are not visible in the viewport

Comment: To make the usernames visible i need to scroll down to make it visible

Comment: The main problem is that order is proper, as i have written in my question